# Finding integer solutions to $y^2=x^3-2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

I have the equation:
$$y^2=x^3-2$$
It seems to be deceivingly simple, yet I simply cannot crack it. It is obviously equivalent to finding a perfect cube that is two more than a perfect square, and a brute force check shows no solutions other than $y=5$ and $x=3$ under 10,000. 
However, I can't prove it.

Are there other integer solutions to this equation? If so, how many? If not, can you prove that there aren't?

Bonus: What about the more general equation"
$$y^2=x^3-c$$
Where $c$ is a positive integer?

Comment: The specific equation here is an exercise in Chapter 2 of M. Ram Murty, J. Esmonde, *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory*. As André implied it depends on unique factorization in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. The general case (IIRC AKA Mordell Curves) is much more difficult.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you possibly link me to some pages about unique factorization? The Wolfram Mathworld page isn't that helpful.

Comment: @TreFox: Unfortunately, for generational reasons and because I have not taught number theory for a while, I am not familiar with online stuff.

Comment: @AndréNicolas No problem! Could you perhaps explain a bit about what $Z[\sqrt{-2}]$ means? I know Z is the set of all integers, but I'm not sure what the square root of -2 means in this context.

Comment: It is the collection of all numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{-2}$, where $a$ and $b$ range over the ordinary integers. As to $\sqrt{-2}$, if you are not yet acquainted with complex numbers, it would take a while to explain. Such extensions of the ordinary integers are surprisingly often useful in solving problems about ordinary integers. This kind of number theory is usually not done (in North America at least) until the second or third year of university.  By the way, Wikipedia is often less terse than MathWorld.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh, that makes sense! Thank you for your help! I am acquainted with complex numbers, I just wondered what the square root of negative 2 meant in that context, inside the Z.

Comment: @TreFox: You are welcome. Fully answering the question you asked (that is, showing there are no solutions other than the two you found by experimentation) is not easy, and definitely not Grade 7 material!

Comment: @TreFox: The ring of numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{-1}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, that is, the ring of Gaussian Integers, is more generally useful, because of its close connection with sums of two squares.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Wow, just skimming some articles about this, and this is some super interesting and useful stuff. I think you might have just given me a project for the summer! Thanks! One more question - one of the proofs I'm reading talks about a gaussian integer being prime. How can a gaussian integer be prime? Is it if $a$ and $b$ are prime, or something else?  Sorry to bother you with all this, by the way, I really appreciate the time you've taken.

Comment: First a **unit** is any of the Gaussian integers $1$, $-1$, $i$, or $-i$. A Gaussian prime is a non-unit $z$ such that whenever $z=xy$ where $x$ and $y$ are Gaussian integers, then one of $x$ or $y$ is a unit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only integral solutions to your first problem are $(3, \pm 5)$. The general class of equations are known as Mordell's equation. [A fairly elaborate discussion and case by case analysis is provided here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf).

Comment: So am I right in thinking this is probably a typo if it appeared on an Algebra 1 math worksheet?

Comment: No. Your thinking is not right. Solutions to $y^2=x^3-2$ can be done in Algebra $1$.

Comment: How would one go about solving that equation in Algebra 1 - other than just trial and error?

Comment: @TreFox As mentioned in the article on page $7$.

Comment: We have never been introduced to modulo (in class, that is. I'm sure some, myself included, know what it is), nor the notation $Z[\sqrt{2}]$ (Which I assume has something to do with the unique factorization everyone is mentioning?).  Is unique factorization usually a 7th grade topic that I perhaps know by a different name?

Comment: The factorization $x^2+2=(x-\sqrt{-2})(x+\sqrt{-2})$ is already not Grade 7 stuff, and neither is the  ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. Perhaps you were just supposed to play around and find the solutions $x=\pm 5$, $y=3$ and report that you had found no others.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yes, considering the question next to this one is about finding the area of a square with a width of 5, I would assume trial and error was expected here. Perhaps I should come in on the first day of school with a fully fledged proof of the general case - it could be my project this summer :)

Answer (score 6):

Fact : $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$ is Unique factorization domain.
lemma : in every UFD, if the product of two numbers, which are relatively prime is a cube, then each of them must be a cube.
There is no any solution

$$x^3 = (y+\sqrt{-2})\times(y-\sqrt{-2})$$

the greatest common divisor of these factors will divide 2-times the $\sqrt{-2}$,
which is lead to only finitly many cases. (some cases can be shown impossible, only by the modular an congrunce arithmetic.)

finally we have:
$$y+\sqrt{-2}=(a+b\sqrt{-2})^3$$
which lead us to the system of equations as follows:
$$a^3-6ab^2=y$$ and
$$3a^2b-2b^3=1$$
then
$$b(3a^2-2b^2)=1$$
which implies the assertion.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! Your post will be easier to read if you format it. Please see this [informative tutorial on formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I can't type in that way, I can't understand what is the proble. for example when I want to write " a-sub-1" .... I type a_1 but the result does not differ, i can't understand what should I do.

Comment: You need to surround the expression with dollar signs. So to get $a_1$, type `$a_1$`. If you use two dollar signs, then it will appear centred on a new line. For example, `$$a_1$$` produces $$a_1$$